# Merge multiple arrays php

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I really need some help to figure this one out.

I've got a number of arrays and i would like to merge some of them. It looks like as following.

```
            while ($row = $db->fetch_array($result_set)) {
                $year           = $row['year(Tidspunkt)'];
                $month_num      = $row['month(Tidspunkt)'];
                $month      = $cal->name_of_month($row['month(Tidspunkt)']);
                $type           = $row['Klubtype'];
                $visits         = $row['count(Handling)'];
                $days_in_month = $cal->days_in_month($month_num,$year);
                $avg           = $visits / $days_in_month;
                $object_array[]= array('month' => $month , 'visits' => $visits, 'type' => $type, 'avg' => $avg);
            }
            return $month_array;
```

And the output looks like this

```
Array ( 
     [0] => Array ( [month] => Januar [visits] => 891 [type] => FK [avg] => 28.7419354839 ) 
     [1] => Array ( [month] => Januar [visits] => 23 [type] => UK [avg] => 0.741935483871 ) 
)
```

Now I would like to merge these two arrays based on the value of month. Imagine when I've got arrays for a whole year. Then it would be nice to have 12 arrays instead of 24.

Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be what you want...

```
$newArray = array();

foreach($array as $value) {

   $month = $value['month'];
   unset($value['month']);
   $newArray[$month][] = $value;
}
```

This will give you something like...

```
Array ( 
     ['Januar'] => Array (
        [0] => Array( [visits] => 891 [type] => FK [avg] => 28.7419354839 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [visits] => 23 [type] => UK [avg] => 0.741935483871 ) 
)
```

Comment: It does the job but I'm concerned about having the month value as "key" and not as "value". If you know what I mean?

Comment: @nickifrandsen Why does it concern you? If it is not the key, then you will need some sort of unique key, which *could* be the numeric equivalent, e.g. `January => 1`.

Comment: It concern me because I would like to echo out the month. I don't know if it makes any sense. However I know i will doing a similar thing later on which makes it useful to have the e.g "month" as key and "January" as value. Like this 'month' => 'January'. I hope this explains my minor concerns.

Comment: @nickifrandsen You can echo the month by referencing the key, e.g. `foreach($months as $month => $value) { ... }`. You can `echo $month` to get the month.

Comment: of course. I don't know why didn't think of that. Thank you very much for the help :)